# How I use custom local_part of email address in Amazon Simple Email Service?

Tags: amazon-ses

When I first sent a test message with Amazon SES, the MAIL_FROM was `0101015825ed6274-5b0cad8d-ddb6-425b-9802-782cc554497a-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com`.

In most email programs that address is hidden in the header, and it appears to be FROM a more human-friendly address. This is not the case when using an email to MMS gateway, which displays the spammy looking MAIL_FROM address to the user.

I figured out how to change the MAIL_FROM domain, but that just changes it to something like: `0101015825ed6274-5b0cad8d-ddb6-425b-9802-782cc554497a-000000@my_domain.com`.

Is it possible to change the spammy-looking string of characters in the MAIL_FROM to a customized, human-friendly, less spammy-looking local_part of the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.

The local_part of the `MAIL FROM` address is a unique, opaque identifier that SES uses for feedback tracking -- linking backsplatter bounces from poorly-behaving mail gateways that "reject" undeliverable mail by first accepting it and then firing back a separate bounce message... as well as spam complaints and out-of-office auto-responders, back to the original sender, message, and recipient.

That's why of the [configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from-set.html) of a custom `MAIL FROM` domain involves setting the domain's MX record to point to `feedback-smtp.[aws-region].amazonses.com` -- it collects those responses and correlates them back to the original message.

Techniques of this nature are necessary due to weaknesses in the design of SMTP itself, where it is difficult, unreliable, or impossible to otherwise correlate such events back to the original message that actually triggered them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Since this was not possible with Amazon SES, I ended up buying a G Suite account ($5-10/month).  This allows me to send from my own domain name with whatever local_part I want, and the sending limits were sufficient for my needs.  https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en